# How can i authenticate a POST request in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests

I built a custom view where, when the page is loaded, the view sends a request to an external Python script. This script should retrieve some data of the user who sent the request and send it back as a response to the Django view, which will show it to the user.

The problem with my actual code is that i don't know how to authenticate the request sent from the external script to Django. In order for Django to accept the request and show the user their data, it needs to be authenticated with the user's crdeentials. The problem is that the external Python script **doesn't** have those credentials, unless the Django view sends it first.

So, **X** user is using the view, the view sends a request to the external script, the external script should send a response with the user's data and the credentials of user **X**. Same goes if user Y is using the view and so on.

Since this service is handling personal data, i would like it to be as safe as possible.

Here is what i have:
This is how the request is sent from the external script to the Django view

```
import json

import requests

session = requests.session()
token = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginview/')

session.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/loginview/',
             data={
                 'username': '**'USER**',
                 'password': '**PASSWORD**',
                 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token})

token = session.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myTestView/')
data = json.dumps({'test': 'value'})
session.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myTestView/',
             data={
                 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token,
                 'data': data})
```

The whole problem is there on the fields USERNAME and PASSWORD. This external script is not able to get the credentials of the user who sent the request dynamically, unless i send them first with the first Django request.

Here is how the request is accepted:

```
@login_required
def myTestView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get('data')
        print(json.loads(data))
        print('received.')

    response = HttpResponse(get_token(request))
    return response    

def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponse('authenticated')
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden('wrong username or password')

    response = HttpResponse(get_token(request))
    return response
```

So here `login_view` accepts the request and the other view does whatever i need to do with it.

Tl;Dr My Django service should send a request to an external script, the external script as a response sends something back to Django. Django needs to authenticate this request somehow; since the external script is separated from Django, there is no way for it to retrieve the credentials, unless i send them first.

Comment: I'm afraid I really don't get the point of this "external script" thing.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers please read the question. I said that the external script is supposed to retrieve some data and perform some actions and then send it back as a response to Django. I would do everything from Django but i can't, this is why i'm doing this. Also i don't think that the core of this question it's the point of the external script

Comment: I did read the question - else I wouldn't have posted this comment. " I would do everything from Django but i can't" => Why ???

Comment: The way authentication works in the browser is by sending the session cookie in each request. Django then checks whether the session belongs to an authenticated user or not. So you need to catch the cookie in the response to the login and send it with every subsequent request. Or, something that would be more common for an API accessed by a script, use some form of token authentication (django-rest-framework provides that). You probably want to use DRF anyway since your views are API views.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ok, i get that it wasn't very clear from the question, but trust me this is how i need to do it. It's sort of a microservice structure; the external script is hosted on another server and has to do tasks that i can't do or that would be too heavy to perform with Django

Comment: Thanks @dirkgroten, so let me see if i'm getting this right: Django view sends the cookie along with the request > external script sends back its data along with the cookie > Django checks if it belongs to an authenticated user?

Comment: @Jack022 ok it does make more sense indeed (note that for what you describe you could possibly use something like celery - or other distributed async task queue - instead but I assume you already discarded this solution for various reasons).

Comment: Correct, except you should say: In every view, Django sends the cookie along with the **response**.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, i know Celery and i'm probably going to use it for other features, but in this case, doing everything from Django would be just too heavy; also considered that it's sort of a microservice architecture, Django would also be a bit overkill

Comment: Note also that all your post requests should contain the csrf cookie (not just pass the csrf token as data), if the views they access aren't csrf exempt. Just look at the request/response headers in your browser to see how it works.

Comment: ok @dirkgroten! So,instead of USERNAME and PASSWORD there should be my cookie's variables?

Comment: no, you still have to login once, otherwise the user won't be logged in. So not **instead**.

Comment: Yes but the user is logged from the site, the whole point of this is that i cannot have USERNAME and PASSWORD there because there is no way for the external script to know the user's nickname and password, since the service can be used from different users and it is not connected to the database that django uses to handle users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to add a different authentication mechanism (which would be more appropriate for an API, e.g. [token authentication](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)), then the steps to do this are to replicate what your browser does.

(Tip: Look at the request and response headers in your browser debug tools during a normal login sequence)

1. Fetch the login view to receive a CSRF cookie and the CSRF token.
2. Send the POST request to the login view, including the CSRF cookie. The response will contain the session cookie which you should use for every subsequent request.
3. Now you can POST to any other view, by including the session cookie.

Comment: I can use a different mechanism if it would be easier to do; but the main point is that it needs to be safe. So the user must get only the data that concerns them, not other users for example

Comment: Token authentication is more common for APIs, you fetch the token once and send it in the header of each subsequent request. But it's basically the same as sending a cookie header with the session so it doesn't really matter. You just should make sure all these requests are over HTTPS because both token and session id are sensitive.

Comment: So, with the token it would work like this: Django sends the token in the header of the request > external receives the request and sends back the json data along with the token?

Comment: No, with the token authentication you make a special login view that returns the token in the json response of the login view. Then your script sends that token in the header of every subsequent request. The token is stored locally for each user (it's how mobile apps do it). When the token expires, the app logs in again and receives a new token.

Comment: Ok, but in this case i don't understand this: how does the external get the token, so that it can be authenticated?

Comment: By logging in with username password (post to login view, step 2 in my answer above).

Comment: Ok, can you point me to some example code for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the DRF documentation and source code [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#by-exposing-an-api-endpoint)

Comment: Is that what you mean? https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/22/how-to-implement-token-authentication-using-django-rest-framework.html

Comment: That is okay, but in this case i don't have an external script that needs to access a DRF API endpoint, in my case is the external script sending data to Django, or am i getting this wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205151/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-jack022).